# How do I view the last X hours in my production.log in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unix

I am on a very bad internet connection and need to check **only today's** portion of the `production.log` file in the console.

How can I do this?

Comment: what's about log rotation :)

Comment: thanks.. maybe long term solution.. just want a quick look

Comment: that's a bit difficult because not every line has a date before :) otherwise awk or grep helps.

Comment: can you pull up the last x lines?

Comment: @Abram, Try this : `tail -n 50 production.log` for getting last 50 lines from log file.

Comment: Ah thanks. Someone (ie you) should post that if they want points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in comment,

```
can you pull up the last x lines?
```

You can use this,

```
tail -n 50 production.log
```

To get the last 50 lines from the `production.log` file.

**(OR)**

If you want,

```
tail -f production.log
```

which will monitor the `production.log` file for the appended data.